# Passing Array to Facebook Object while posting to users Timeline

Tags: java, android, facebook

How do you pass an array in android to the Route Property of an object type. The Route Property is an option while creating an object type for your application in the Open Graph. I can't find this anywhere!

The route should display on a Facebook Timeline in a Map Layout.

Thanks!

Matt

Answer (score 0):

My guess is as good as yours, but try using a `JSONObject` to construct a compatible array:

```
JSONObject routeProperty = new JSONObject();
routeProperty.put("Cat");
routeProperty.put("Dog");
```

Then call `routeProperty.toString()` to pass it into the params or options for your object.

Comment: Hi Jesse, after many trial and error attempts at configuring my Facebook object properties I finally was able to figure out the route array portion of posting a route to the timeline. However the coordinate cap seems to be about 220. I will post again so you can see the the HTML file

Comment: <meta property="my app domain:route:latitude"           content="41.891049933333335" /> 
  <meta property="my app domain:route:longitude"          content="12.480437916666666" />  I needed to add lat and long meta data tags to the HTML file. Obviously I wasn't able to post the whole file here. In the real file I have about 550 coordinates. When the route posts to the timeline you only see about 220 coordinates. Do you know anything about this array limit?

Comment: Please submit a bug report at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/create about this issue and I or someone else can try to take a look at it.  Mention that you and Jesse Chen spoke about it.  It probably would be good to post the link to the bug report so other users here can track it in case they are also interested.

Comment: Bug Report has been created: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/461737010532033